# Seeking big-picture guidance on how to incorporate a sortable grid into Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I'd like to make a 2x16 grid where you can sort the 16 rows (not items in individual columns) and, for each row, select either the left or the right element. Each grid will have an image, and after you're done, the data will be captured and submitted to a spreadsheet.

The grid should be available to multiple users of the same spreadsheet.

My first thought was Google Forms, but a) you can only use the default "ranking" button up to 10 ranks, and I need it to go up to 16, and b) there seem to be additional restrictions.

I've found jQuery code for a movable grid, but it doesn't seem that you can ask Google Spreadsheet to use the jQuery library (I could be wrong on this, it's my first time using jQuery and I'm poorly self-taught in javascript... my first test was a simple "$(document).ready(function)" but Google Spreadsheets complains that $ isn't defined and that (document) isn't defined.

If you can explain how to use jQuery code in the spreadsheet, then I should be good.

Alternately, I figured I can try my hand at creating the sortable grid elsewhere, and then transferring the data to Google Spreadsheet. I might try Google Sites. However, I'm not sure a method exists to then transfer that data over to Google Docs. I could make a website where you sort the grid, click a button, and get your output, then I could have the user copy that and paste it into a Spreadsheet sell which is set up to parse the output and feed it into the sheet... but that seems like a lot of work for the people who are inputting data.

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is a library that works in JavaScript executed in your Browser , in other words, in client side JavaScript.

Google Apps Script is a server side language based on JavaScript but it has a lot of specific features allowing to communicate with Google Apps services (and others...).

One of these specific features is [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/), it will allow you to develop custom applications as webapps (standalone application you run in your browser) or spreadsheet/document hosted extensions that you can run from a 'popup' window or from the sidebar in your Google document/spreadsheet.

These "auxiliary apps" built with HTML Service can use JQUERY libraries with very few restrictions. Reading the documentation I refer to above should give you enough information to start with.

Give it a try and come back with specific question if you meet some difficulties.

Comment: Wish I could provide more details, commenting is limited...

I have experience with Google Apps Script; my javascript is limited to what I've learned playing with GAS.

I cannot get a user interface to display. I decided to try the UIApp instead of HTMLService just as a learning tool.

I have copied/pasted the code in from the documentation, and still nothing.

I suspect the problem is where I'm calling the function from. The code builds a UI App, and at the end returns "myApp". Should it automatically display when the function is called, just by returning the UI? The doc implies so, but...

Comment: are you trying to build a standalone webapp or a window in a doc/spreadsheet ?

Comment: I'm just trying to display a popup window with no functionality within Google spreadsheets. But even copying the actual example from the documentation results in nothing happening. The script is running; I can make a "toast" popup through the function (if I add it before the "return myApp" line, of course).

Comment: When you build a UI embedded in a sheet you have to use the spreadsheetApp show() method instead of a simple return. Link:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs.  Look for the chapter about custom dialog.

Comment: Also, for new version of spreadsheets, read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui

Comment: Thanks. I wondered if the new shorts changed it, but I didn't see any indication that the example was deprecated or outdated. I'm really excited that you shared this!